# How React HOC function knows the props of a Component that put into it as a parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I try to understand how React HOCs work. The following code that will be written bellow WORKS, but I cannot understand WHY it works:

```
const MyHOC = (WrappedComponent) => { 

    return (props) => {   //these props are the props of a WrappedComponent
        return (
            <div style={{color: "red", fontSize: "100px"}}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MyHOC
```

After that, I use my hoc here:

```
import MyHOC from "../HOC/MyHOC"   //hoc

const SomeStuff = (props) => {  

    return (
        <div>
            Hello world!!!
            {
                props.data.map(item => {
                    return <div>{item}</div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
//our component wrapped with a hoc
export default MyHOC(SomeStuff)
```

And then, I implement my components here, where they successfully work

```
import SomeStuff from "./COMPONENTS/SomeStuff"

function App() {

  const list = ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']


  return (
    <div>
      <SomeStuff data={list}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the first snippet of a code written above, we created a function that takes "WrappedComponent" as a parameter. This function returns another function, which takes props as a parameter.

MY QUESTION IS:
HOW THE RETURNED FUNCTION KNOWS WHAT PROPS PUT AS PARAMETER, IF WE DID NOT DECLARE THEM ANYWHERE.

We put a component as a parameter to a PARENT function, BUT React SOMEHOW FOUND OUT THAT WE NEED THE PROPS used in this "WrappedComponent"

How this was possible?

Please, please, please help me to find an answer...

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You did declare them using `<WrappedComponent {...props}/>`, that will take the props that you passed to the HOC and also pass it down to the child.  The spread operator `...` will split up the prop array the HOC received and pass it on to the child as individual props, as if you just normally called that component.

Answer (score 0):

> HOW THE RETURNED FUNCTION KNOWS WHAT PROPS PUT AS PARAMETER, IF WE DID
> NOT DECLARE THEM ANYWHERE.

When you peform:

```
<SomeStuff data={list}/>
```

you're passing the `data` prop into the `SomeStuff` (wrapped) component, which is exported here:

```
export default MyHOC(SomeStuff)
```

this first calls the `MyHOC()` function and returns the `(props) => {` function, which acts as the wrapping component for SomeStuff. This wrapping component is used when we export it (seen above at the beginning of this answer). As a result, the wrapping component gets passed through `data={list}` which is accessed via the `props` argument of the returned `(props) => {` function - in your example, props would be an object that looks (roughly) like so `{data: list}`.

> React SOMEHOW FOUND OUT THAT WE NEED THE PROPS used in this
> "WrappedComponent"

Your wrapping component is able to forward the props object into the actual `SomeStuff` component via the spread syntax:

```
<WrappedComponent {...props}/>
```

this takes every (own-enumerable) `key: value` pair from the `props` object, and adds it as a `key={value}` prop to the target component (that being the actual SomeStuff component).

Answer (score 0):

SomeStuff is being with data as a prop in main App.

SomeStuff being exported is wrapped by HOC as declared.

```
export default MyHOC(SomeStuff)
```

So, component ie. function that is exported from SomeStuff module is somewhat:

```
(props) => {   //these props are the props of a WrappedComponent
        return (
            <div style={{color: "red", fontSize: "100px"}}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here, WrappedComponent is SomeStuff and the data (ie. prop) you passed is being passed as it is to the SomeStuff component.